# Invisible Recaptcha Form Validation - Not Submitting/Ignoring Form Action

Tags: jquery, forms, recaptcha

I have a form that I'm using invisible Recaptcha on - and I want to validate a field prior to submission.  This has turned out to be a far bigger pain than anticipated, mostly due to when the ReCaptcha instance would be rendered.  But - using their docs - I've set up:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script>
function onSubmit(token) {
    alert("Submitting");
    document.getElementById('myform').submit();
  }

  function validate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!document.getElementById('field').value) {
      alert("You must add text to the required field");
    } else {
      grecaptcha.execute();
    }
  }

  function onload() {
    var element = document.getElementById('submit');
    element.onclick = validate;
  }
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="myform" action="hello.php" method="POST">
     Name: (required) <input id="field" name="field">
     <div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha"
          data-sitekey="haoeghioaehgoiaegoiaeg2831850135"
          data-callback="onSubmit"
          data-size="invisible"></div>
     <button id='submit'>submit</button>
   </form>
<script>onload();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, it will verify that the field has been filled in, it will alert me, but it will not "submit" the action?  It stops at that point.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check developer console for any js error.

Comment: Thank you - I had developer console open but for some reason missed the error.  Turns out that the button having the ID of submit was conflicting with JQuery's submit function.  Changing the ID to "btnsubmit" resolved the issue.

Comment: Great. Good luck.